# how to read images names form cordova.file.tempDirectory using Ng-Cordova

Tags: angularjs, file, cordova, ngcordova, cordova-plugin-file

We want read images names form `cordova.file.tempDirectory` using file plugin we tried like this

```
 $cordovaFile.readAsText(cordova.file.tempDirectory)
            .then(function (success) {
                 console.log("success2"+success);
                  }, function (error) {
                      console.log("error"+error);
                  });
But We got error


ERROR: Wrong type for parameter "path" of DirectoryEntry.getFile: Expected String, but got Undefined.
2016-08-25 09:23:28.958 DPOD[3482:38292] Error in Success callbackId: File1548160221 : TypeError: Wrong type for parameter "path" of DirectoryEntry.getFile: Expected String, but got Undefined.
```

cordova.file.tempDirectory have only 10 images.So we need 10images name.tell me what wrong in our code.Please guide to us.

Answer (score 0):

**$cordova.readAsText** accepts two arguments **path** and **file**.

```
// READ
$cordovaFile.readAsText(cordova.file.dataDirectory,$scope.inputs.readFile)
  .then(function (success) {
    // success
  }, function (error) {
    // error
  });
```

Try reading the file as an array buffer. See other options for reading files here. [ngCordova file plugin](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/file/)

Make sure to add ngCordova file and appropriate dependency injections. [Installation guide](http://ngcordova.com/docs/install/)